# Why is $store not defined?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am struggling to developed a project with vuejs and vuex, but it does not work with `this.$store.state.count` in the component. Why?

My config:

```
"vuex": "^2.0.0"
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 12
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
    }
  },
  strict: true
})
```

main.js:

```
import store from './vuex/store'
import Vue from 'vue'

new Vue({
  store,
  .
  .
  .
}).$mount('#app')
```

component.js:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: 'landing-page',
    created: () => {
      console.log('status2')
      console.log(this.$store.state.count)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$store' of undefined
```

Comment: The error does not mean that `$store` is not defined. Read carefully. It says that `this` is not defined.

Comment: Oh, yes.  `this` is undefined. Why can't I use `this` here ?

Comment: `this` in the component will refer to it's `data`.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never, ever edit the store directly.

You will ALWAYS trigger mutations.

As so (component.js):

```
<script>
import store from './vuex/store'

export default {
  name: 'landing-page',
  computed: {
    counter () {
      return store.state.count // get state
    }
  },
  created: () => {
    store.commit('increment') // set state
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I just want to get state, not set.

Comment: Edited, to reflect the get part (;

Comment: I don't understand this example as a Vue noob. Examples show me instantiating a store, and passing to Vue. When you import `store` in this example, are you importing an instantiated Vuex object then? Why wouldn't it be passed down in some way from Vue?

Comment: @DaveStein "When you import store in this example, are you importing an instantiated Vuex object then?", Yes. You can also pass it in the Vue as mentioned here: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components to avoid relying on the global singleton...

Answer (score 2):

That is because `this` in arrow function is not what you expect as `this` in "normal function". You can refer to [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or [Javascript ES6 — Arrow Functions and Lexical `this`](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4) for more information